# python generate 3d unstructured grid

Tags: geology, numerical-modelling, interpolation

I would like to create a 3d unstructured grid based on data points with xyz and property.  Can Python do this and what tools?
 My question is quite generic but i can provide more details: the data has easting and northing in UTM coordinates, elevation in masl, and a property value that i define based on soil type which i assign a permeability value or a particle size (ultimately, i would like to interpolate both).  the dataset has about 5000 points for approx 1000 boreholes, so 5 points on average per borehole.

As each borehole has a different number of soil intervals, i think the best is to use an unstructred grid so that the top of soil elevation are respected at each borehole
thanks
f

Comment: Can you specify your question? It is too vague and thus off topic

Comment: i have a data set of 5000 records with coordinates xy and elevation z, and a property k.  i would like to creat a 3d mesh (unstructured) with a node at every data points. The data points are geological contacts on boreholes.

Comment: Welcome to the site. When you want to ask a question you have to be more specific. Therefore can you please read How to ask a good question first?  https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Hi fanfanGis, welcome to SE. There are a number of tools out there for producing unstructured grids. If you can give a bit more context and detail (what is this grid for? What problem are you trying to solve? What have you tried already?), you might get more helpful answers.

Comment: i am building a geological model and i have top contact elevation of soil layers vertically along boreholes.  each  soil layer is defined as a property: k.

Comment: i want to create a 3 d mesh unstructured so that it respects the top s and bottoms of each layer and then interpolate the property between boreholes.  the next step will be to visualoize the model by importing it in another software package such as ceflow or modflow, or perhaps a python package.

Comment: FanfanGis, put everything you answer in comments *also* in your question, please - comments can disappear and the question should contain all necessary information. You can than also fix your typos.

Comment: I edited the question (only visible after review). I added OP comments to the question. @fanfanGis - check the edited question. ty

Comment: thanks for your comments.  i press Done and it publishes the comment but should be only one comment.  my question is quite generic. the data has easting and northing in UTM coordinates, elevation in masl, and a property value that i define based on soil type which i assign a permeability value or a particle size (ultimately, i would like to interpolate both).  as each borehole has a different number of soil intervals, i think the best is to use an unstructred grid so that the top of soil elevation are respected at each borehole.

Comment: The question remains: what to do with the data then? If I understand you correctly, your data is sampled irregularly, and you would like to obtain the (interpolated) values at arbitrary new locations? For this purpose you don't have to create an unstructured grid, you want to create an arbitrary grid (structured or not) from unstructured data. Python functions like http://lagrange.univ-lyon1.fr/docs/scipy/0.17.1/generated/scipy.interpolate.interpn.html could work?

Comment: Have you considered using meshpy? You should be able to set points in there. https://pypi.org/project/MeshPy/